# clases y objetos JS. Pregunta

Tags: javascript

tengo este ejercicio y la verdad no se como resolverlo. podrian ayudarme?

```
function crearClaseEmprendedor() {
  class Emprendedor {
      constructor(nombre, apellido, libros, mascotas) {
          // El constructor de la clase Emprendedor recibe nombre (string), apellido (string), libros (array de objetos), mascotas (array de strings)
          // Inicializar las propiedades del emprendedor con los valores recibidos como argumento
          // Tu código aca:
          this.nombre = nombre,
          this.apellido = apellido,
          this.libros = libros,
          this.mascota = mascota,
          this.emprendedor = function(){
          return{
            nombre: this.nombre,
            apellido: this.apellido,
            libros: this.libros,
            mascotas: this.mascotas,
        }
      }
          }
      addMascota(mascota) {
        // este método debe agregar una mascota (mascota) al arreglo de mascotas del emprendedor.
        // no debe retornar nada.
        // Tu código aca:
          this.mascotas.push(mascota);
      }
      getMascotas() {
          // El método 'getMascotas' debe retornar la cantidad de mascotas que tiene el emprendedor.
          // Ej:
          // Suponiendo que el emprendedor tiene estas mascotas: ['perro', 'gato']
          // emprendedor.getMascotas() debería devolver 2

          // Tu código aca:

      }

      addBook(book, autor) {
          // El método 'addBook' recibe un string 'book' y un string 'autor' y debe agregar un objeto:
          // { nombre: book, autor: autor} al arreglo de libros del emprendedor.
          // No debe retornar nada.

          // Tu código aca:

      }

      getBooks() {
          // El método 'getBooks' debe retornar un arreglo con sólo los nombres del arreglo de libros del emprendedor.
          // Ej:
          // Suponiendo que el emprendedor tiene estos libros: [{nombre: 'El señor de las moscas',autor: 'William Golding'}, {nombre: 'Fundacion', autor: 'Isaac Asimov'}]
          // emprendedor.getBooks() debería devolver ['El señor de las moscas', 'Fundacion']

          // Tu código aca:

      }

      getFullName() {
          // El metodo getFullName debe retornar un string con el nombre y apellido del emprendedor.
          // ej:
          // Suponiendo que el emprendedor tiene: nombre: 'Elon' y apellido: 'Musk'
          // emprendedor.getFullName() deberia devolver 'Elon Musk'

          // Tu código aca:

      }
  }

  return Emprendedor;
}
```

para saber si se encuentra bien, puedo correr un test por consola usando el comando npm test. Para mi buen entender se ecuentra bien el primer punto, sin embargo me bota error. la verdad no se como desarrollar esto.
no se si alguno me pueda brindar una guia, documentacion o si fuera posible el codigo para analizarlo y entdender en que parte o donde estoy fallando.
se me dificulta bastante el vocabulario usado.

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow, por favor has el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Debes colocar el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento. Te sugiero que leas [example] para que sea más fácil entender lo que buscas. Recuerda que debes demostrar que has investigado previamente antes de recurrir a preguntar. Y por favor si obtienes un error, agrégalo como texto a la pregunta. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Diria que tienes varios problemas de concepto.

Para empezar, no veo que te pidan que crees una funcion que a su vez cree una clase, por lo tanto de momento yo eliminaría la primera línea:

```javascript
function crearClaseEmprendedor() {
```

y al final eliminaría la linea del `return Emprendedor` y su cierre `}`:

```javascript
  return Emprendedor;
}
```

Hecho esto verás que tu código empieza definiendo una clase:

```javascript
class Emprendedor {
```

y termina al final del código actual cerrándola con un corchete de cierre `}`.

Lo que contiene esa clase es un método [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor) y otros métodos adicionales por programar aún.

En este estado, tan solo estas definiendo la clase, nada más, no veras nada en ninguna parte al ejecutar el código, porque no estas usando la clase aún.

Para usar la clase debes instanciar un objeto, lo cual puedes hacer así, al final del código y **fuera** de la clase, y pasándole los parámetros que su constructor espera:

```
instancia = new Emprendedor("Pedro", "Martinez", ["Quijote","Sancho"], ["Perro","Gato"])
```

Y es a partir de ahi, que jugando con la instancia, podras hacer cosas con los métodos de la clase, es decir, por ejemplo:

```javascript
console.log(instancia.getMascotas)
```

Esta instrucción te mostrará en consola el resultado del método `getMascotas` de la instancia de la clase Emprendedor que has creado antes. Actualmente no tiene código, claro, pero para cuando lo tenga que lo sepas.

Y ahora la corrección de la primera parte que ya has hecho:

Segun dice la primera parte del ejercicio, tan solo tienes que inicializar las propiedades, pero cometes errores de sintaxis (pones comas al final de cada linea que sobran) y de concepto (no hay que retornar nada, se usa la instancia para acceder a las propiedades).

Lo que básicamente te estan pidiendo que hagas es esto:

```javascript
    constructor(nombre, apellido, libros, mascotas) {
      // El constructor de la clase Emprendedor recibe nombre (string), apellido (string), libros (array de objetos), mascotas (array de strings)
      // Inicializar las propiedades del emprendedor con los valores recibidos como argumento
      // Tu código aca:
      this.nombre = nombre
      this.apellido = apellido
      this.libros = libros
      this.mascota = mascotas
    }
```

No te piden que retornes nada, pues cuando vayas a crear una instancia de esa clase, implicitamente podrás acceder a esas propiedades directamente con la sintaxis habitual de objeto.

Es decir, si colocas al final del código que he ido explicando esta nueva línea:

```javascript
console.log(instancia.nombre);
```

tiene que aparecerte `Pedro` en la consola de javascript.

Aquí dejo el código completo que puedes ejecutar para ver todo lo que he explicado:

```js
class Emprendedor {
  constructor(nombre, apellido, libros, mascotas) {
    // El constructor de la clase Emprendedor recibe nombre (string), apellido (string), libros (array de objetos), mascotas (array de strings)
    // Inicializar las propiedades del emprendedor con los valores recibidos como argumento
    // Tu código aca:
    this.nombre = nombre
    this.apellido = apellido
    this.libros = libros
    this.mascota = mascotas
  }
  addMascota(mascota) {
    // este método debe agregar una mascota (mascota) al arreglo de mascotas del emprendedor.
    // no debe retornar nada.
    // Tu código aca:
    this.mascotas.push(mascota);
  }
  getMascotas() {
    // El método 'getMascotas' debe retornar la cantidad de mascotas que tiene el emprendedor.
    // Ej:
    // Suponiendo que el emprendedor tiene estas mascotas: ['perro', 'gato']
    // emprendedor.getMascotas() debería devolver 2

    // Tu código aca:

  }

  addBook(book, autor) {
    // El método 'addBook' recibe un string 'book' y un string 'autor' y debe agregar un objeto:
    // { nombre: book, autor: autor} al arreglo de libros del emprendedor.
    // No debe retornar nada.

    // Tu código aca:

  }

  getBooks() {
    // El método 'getBooks' debe retornar un arreglo con sólo los nombres del arreglo de libros del emprendedor.
    // Ej:
    // Suponiendo que el emprendedor tiene estos libros: [{nombre: 'El señor de las moscas',autor: 'William Golding'}, {nombre: 'Fundacion', autor: 'Isaac Asimov'}]
    // emprendedor.getBooks() debería devolver ['El señor de las moscas', 'Fundacion']

    // Tu código aca:

  }

  getFullName() {
    // El metodo getFullName debe retornar un string con el nombre y apellido del emprendedor.
    // ej:
    // Suponiendo que el emprendedor tiene: nombre: 'Elon' y apellido: 'Musk'
    // emprendedor.getFullName() deberia devolver 'Elon Musk'

    // Tu código aca:

  }
}
instancia = new Emprendedor("Pedro", "Martinez", ["Quijote","Sancho"], ["Perro","Gato"])
console.log(instancia.nombre);
```